# How to export Excel with Hindi script to CSV file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, export

I would like to know how to export an excel spreadsheet which contains, say a table of Hindi(for that matter any non-english) script words into a CSV file? I tried 'Save As' --> comma delimited, but the characters weren't preserved. When I opened the *.csv file, all i saw as ?????? characters.

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 10 then you can use this solution:

1. Save As the file
2. Select CSV UTF-8 as the Save As type

I have also attached a screenshot:

[image: CSV File for hindi and any other langauge]